# Best Audit trail mechanism for Spring + JPA + Hibernate application

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa-2.0

I am using Spring 3.0 + JPA2 + Hibernate 4.1 with MySQL 5.5
I am looking to record 5 fields in my tables for audit trail purposes - lastModifiedByUser, lastModifiedTime, createdByUser, createdTime, isActive

I am not deleting any data from the tables, just marking them off as isActive false.

What is the best tool to help me record these audit fields in my tables ?
I am wondering if DB triggers are not the best idea, specially since modifying / creating user  name is also recorded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out Envers, it's built just for this and is part of Hibernate 4.x. You just add an @Audited annotation to your class and it automatically handles versioning of your entities.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of recent tools but long back I was able to do it using interceptors.

You may want to map audit columns also in the Entity class. Define an interceptor t populate these attributes in the entity object before persisting the entity object into database.

Sample Audit interceptor details are available at hibernate : [**Hibernate Interceptors: Audit**](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/events.html). Please follow the steps to achieve the needful done.